# One influxdb, two databases on separate directories

Tags: influxdb

I have two databases, lets call them "one" and "two". I would like "one" to use a ssd disk since this will be my main database. "Two" will contain data older than, let's say, 30 days stored on a normal spinning disk, but still accessible for queries. So "one" data from now to now+29d on an SSD and "two" data from now+30d to something older on a spinning disk.

Is it possible to have to databases in one Influxdb pointing to different directories? Or is there a better way of doing this except having two Influx servers running?

Creating a symlink in the influx data directory could be possible for database "two" linking to a different directory, but it feels kind of hackish.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks that InfluxDB didn't support multi-volume storage (or storage tier) on the configuration level yet, see [here](https://community.influxdata.com/t/can-influxdb-use-more-than-one-storage-for-data-directory/7560).